# Text interferes with positioning of elements

Tags: html, css

The task was to make up the following layout:

[image]

And I did it. But when I tried to add text to the blocks, I catch this problem:

[image]

The positioning of the elements is broken, I cant understand what is the reason. The code:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
    <section class="content">
        <div class="main">
            <code class="description">&lt;Section&gt;</code>
        </div>
        <aside class="attachment">
            <div class="first">
                <code class="description">&lt;Aside 1&gt;</code>
            </div>
            <div class="second">
                <code class="description">&lt;Aside 2&gt;</code>
            </div>
        </aside>
    </section>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
/* Content */
.content {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin: 20px;
}

.main {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 600px;
    height: 700px;

    border-radius: 5%;
    border: 2px solid #849942;
    background: #8aab26;

    margin-right: 150px;
    text-align: center;
}

.attachment {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 600px;
    height: 700px;
}

.attachment .first {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 60%;
    height: 45%;

    border-radius: 5%;
    border: 2px solid #849942;
    background: #8aab26;

    margin-bottom: 10%;
    text-align: center;
}

.attachment .second {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 60%;
    height: 45%;

    border-radius: 5%;
    border: 2px solid #849942;
    background: #8aab26;

    text-align: center;
}

.description {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    top: 45%;
}
```

I also tried to remove the second block of the attachment and then the elements were located correctly. I know there are many other ways to make up this layout. But I realy want know what is the reason of this bug. I need help with my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can use this code but you can read this to solve your problem

[w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_align-items.asp)

```css
.content {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin: 20px;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center
}

.main {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 600px;
    height: 700px;

    border-radius: 5%;
    border: 2px solid #849942;
    background: #8aab26;

    margin-right: 150px;
    text-align: center;
}

.attachment {
   
    width: 600px;
    height: 700px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content:space-between
}

.attachment .first {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 60%;
    height: 45%;

    border-radius: 5%;
    border: 2px solid #849942;
    background: #8aab26;

    margin-bottom: 10%;
    text-align: center;
}

.attachment .second {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 60%;
    height: 45%;

    border-radius: 5%;
    border: 2px solid #849942;
    background: #8aab26;

    text-align: center;
}

.description {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    top: 45%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
    <section class="content">
        <div class="main">
            <code class="description">&lt;Section&gt;</code>
        </div>
        <aside class="attachment">
            <div class="first">
                <code class="description">&lt;Aside 1&gt;</code>
            </div>
            <div class="second">
                <code class="description">&lt;Aside 2&gt;</code>
            </div>
        </aside>
    </section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `vertical-align` property to your `.main` element

```css
/* Content */
.content {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin: 20px;
}

.main {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 600px;
    height: 700px;

    border-radius: 5%;
    border: 2px solid #849942;
    background: #8aab26;

    margin-right: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.attachment {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 600px;
    height: 700px;
}

.attachment .first {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 60%;
    height: 45%;

    border-radius: 5%;
    border: 2px solid #849942;
    background: #8aab26;

    margin-bottom: 10%;
    text-align: center;
}

.attachment .second {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 60%;
    height: 45%;

    border-radius: 5%;
    border: 2px solid #849942;
    background: #8aab26;

    text-align: center;
}

.description {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    top: 45%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
    <section class="content">
        <div class="main">
            <code class="description">&lt;Section&gt;</code>
        </div>
        <aside class="attachment">
            <div class="first">
                <code class="description">&lt;Aside 1&gt;</code>
            </div>
            <div class="second">
                <code class="description">&lt;Aside 2&gt;</code>
            </div>
        </aside>
    </section>
</body>
```